# Actualizar Kali

Tags: linux

Buenas, acabo de instalar la imagen de kali en mi ordenador. Quería instalar los headers pero cuando intento hacer un:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

veo que me da error, ya que la versión de mi Kali es la 4.13 y la que está en el repositorio caché (visto con el comando `apt-cache search linux-headers`) es la 4.14. Intento actualizar el kali mediante los comandos siguientes pero no hay forma de pasar de la 4.13 a la 4.14.

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

He hecho los tres pero creo que el problema es que el update no me reconoce que hay nuevas versiones del sistema operativo.

He revisado el fichero /etc/apt/sources.list y contiene el por defecto repositorio

`deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib`

He añadido los siguiente por si se encotaba en alguno pero no me reconoce nada.

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib    non-free
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
```

[image: salida de pantalla con el repositorio by default:]

[image: salida de pantalla con todos los repos]

Sigue sin actualizar.¿Alguna solución a esto?

Answer (score 1):

Auque no es un tema de programación y te van a reñir, puedo sugerirte que primero debes asegurarte que los sources del apt están correctos. Como no nos los pasas, no podemos saber si el problema está ahí. Deberías tener al mínimo:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
```

Y luego:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Si esto de ta error, nos ayudaría mucho conocerlo, porque tampoco nos comentas el error que te sale.

No se si esto te ayudará, pero en realidad solo he buscado en google por "kali" "4.14" "kernel" "headers" y me ha salido en el primer resultado este enlace:

http://lewiscomputerhowto.blogspot.com.es/2015/04/how-to-updateinstall-kernel-headers-in.html

Te lo digo porque si esto no funciona, tal vez prefieras buscarlo antes de preguntar ;)

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, he resuelto el problema de la siguiente manera.

1) He descargado la imagen y los headers con los siguientes comandos

```
apt-cache search linux-headers

apt-get install linux-headers-(el que corresponda)

apt-cache search linux-image

apt-get install linux-image-(la que corresponda)
```

2) Una vez descargado esto hay que pasar la imagen que se encuentra en /usr/src a /boot/

3) Por último hay que actualizar el grub para que los cambios se incorporen.

```
sudo update-grub
```

Nota: si tienes partición con otro Linux como yo, tendrás que actualizar el grub de arranque en mi caso el que usa es el de Ubuntu no el de Kali.